# Do I need to turn off my HVAC system while drywall project going on?

Tags: hvac

Do I need to turn off my HVAC system when dry wall guys hanging and finishing dry wall.
its 5-7 days work. I don't want HVAC to sucks drywall's dust. I can't simply block the return vent in basement.

Comment: Put in a pleated filter. The white kind, not the fiberglass. Also, a box fan and a filter stuck on the back makes a good temporary dust collector.

Comment: This is what our HVAC guy recommends. He actually has a couple of old furnaces that he keeps and loans out to people who are building. He'll install an old one as a temporary heat source if it's needed when drywall is being done during cold weather, then pull it and install their new/permanent one, once the work is done.

Answer (score 2):

I did and generally recommend it.
If they are good, they will be creating a negative pressure situation where air is being pulled through the work location and blowing out a window or door to stop drywall dust form going everywhere as it will regardless of whether your HVAC is on or not (it is insidious).   But unless you have a hepa level filter in your system, it is going to suck in drywall dust if it is running.  And good filters will get clogged with drywall dust quickly. If you have air blowing out vents in that area and a return pulling in air, you are going to have drywall dust going through your air duct system.